# I accidentally removed the Trash folder at /local/share/Trash. How to recover it?

Tags: 13.04, dual-boot

How to recover the trash folder that I deleted from /local/share/Trash. Will it cause any problems on my system?

Comment: Since the trash folder is already referenced, you should be able to just run `sudo mkdir /local/share/Trash`. Just make sure you don't reboot before you do, as that may cause some problems.

Comment: You don't need to do anything. Trash folder will be recreated when needed. If you need to **recover the files you had in Trash folder** you should clearly state that.

Answer (score 0):

The trash folder is found here

```
/home/username/.local/share/Trash
```

If it's not there check here

```
/root/.local/share/Trash
```